# Commuting Dirac spinor with scalar field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, spinors

I have two Lagrangians which only differ in their interaction term - one of them has $L_{Yuk_{1}}$ while the other has $L_{Yuk_{2}}$. I want to know if this two interaction Lagrangians are equivalent. For that, I need to know how to commute scalar field operators, $\phi$, with Dirac spinor operators, $\psi$. How could I do so?

$$L_{Yuk_{1}}=-i\lambda\overline{\psi}\gamma^{5}\psi\phi$$

$$L_{Yuk_{2}}=-\lambda\phi\overline{\psi}\gamma^{5}\psi$$

Comment: Then, does that mean these terms are equivalent if $\phi$ is a scalar in the first lagrangian and a pseudo-scalar in the second (and vice-versa)? The fields would not be the same, but the interaction and the Feynman rules would, is that it?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Can you please check this?

Answer (score 0):

Scalars and Spinors commute, so your two expressions are equivalent up to a factor of i.

Answer (score 0):

The lagrangian is a scalar under the spacetime symmetry group (Poincare group, CPT, gauge invariance etc) so, in particular, there can be no open indices. Your interaction consists of the pseudoscalar-like vertex $\sim \bar \psi_{\alpha} \gamma^5_{\alpha \beta} \psi_{\beta}$ so it doesn't matter whether the scalar $\phi$ is put 'before' or 'after' this combination. This means $L_{Yuk,1}$ and $L_{Yuk,2}$ differ only by a factor $i$.

Comment: So, are both Lagrangians equivalent if for $L_{Yuk,1}$ we have defined
$\gamma^{5}=i\gamma^{0}\gamma^{1}\gamma^{2}\gamma^{3}$, while for
$L_{Yuk,2}$ we have $\gamma^{5}=-i\gamma^{0}\gamma^{1}\gamma^{2}\gamma^{3}$,
with $\lambda$ real?

Comment: That would certainly satisfy the hermiticity of the two lagrangians with $\phi$ a scalar but what about the resulting Feynman rule with regards to the presence of the factor $i$?

Comment: When you say "$\phi$ a scalar" you really mean "pseudo-scalar", right? The Feynman vertex would be $-i\lambda\gamma^{5}$, the same for both Lagrangians, right?

Comment: Yes I meant pseudoscalar for the yuk,1 and scalar for yuk,2, if you are using the redefined $\gamma_5$ for the latter. Where does the $i$ come from in the Feynman rule for yuk,2 though?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is confusing me again. The way I see it, $\phi$ would be a scalar in yuk,1 and pseudo-scalar in yuk,2, if the gammas are as I said. Regarding the Feynman rule, I don't see what you mean. Could you extend and clarify this issues in your answer? I'm just a begginer in qft. If you can help I would be glad. Thank you.

Comment: For yuk,1 to be invariant under parity , need the vertex $\bar \psi \gamma^5 \psi$ to couple to a pseudoscalar $\phi$, no? Usually the $i$ in the Feynman rule originates from an $i$ in the interaction term.

Comment: Take the scalar [scalar yukawa coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_interaction). There's no $i$ in the interaction term, however, the Feynman vertex is $-ig$, has you know. The same goes for $\phi^{4}$ theory.

Comment: I’ve been sloppy with my expression - in e.g the path integral formalism the lagrangian appears in $e^{iS}$. So if you have an $i$ in the interaction vertex it won’t appear in the Feynman rule and vice versa

Comment: Sidequestion: is $\gamma^{5} = \gamma_{5}$?

Comment: See here, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66605/what-is-the-gamma-five-matrix-gamma-5 depends on how you define $\gamma_5$. If this means you lower all the indices on the right hand side then $\gamma_5 = - \gamma^5$

Comment: Ok, then do you see any circumstance under which both lagrangians would be equivalent? Would the weyl representation for Yuk,2 and the Dirac representation for Yuk,1 make it?

Comment: At the moment I don’t see any way but I too am not an expert in this so take what I said with a punch of salt :) However as was pointed out above, to get hermiticity of both lagrangians, one needs to interpret $\phi$ differently in each case, once as a pseudoscalar and second as a scalar.

Comment: Also, since AFT didn’t provide an answer to your question you should tag users @username to make sure they receive your message (as in the above unanswered comment below the question)